# How to reset other values when one is introduced in React with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Having this validation schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  second: yup.number(),
  minute: yup.number(),
  triggerName: yup.string().required()
});
```

- triggerName should be required but when I write something for `minute` input, the `second` input should reset and vice versa.

  `const { handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });`

...

```
<Input inputId='second' type='number' {...register('second')} />
<Input inputId='minute' type='number' {...register('minute')} />
<Input inputId='trigger-name' label='triggerName' {...register('triggerName')} />
```

Tried to do something like the following but it throws errors:

```
<Input inputId='second' type='number' {...reset(), register('second')} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register` returns an object with below structure:

```
{ 
  onChange: function(){},
  onBlur: function(){},
  ref: function(){}
}
```

At the moment you are just passing the object which has returned from `register` function, but you can add some other functionality to your inputs' `onChange` like below example (here we reset one another field in the form by calling `resetField`):

```
const Input = React.forwardRef(({ inputId, ...otherProps }, ref) => {
  return <input id={inputId} ref={ref} {...otherProps} />;
});

const schema = yup.object().shape(
  {
    second: yup
      .number()
      .nullable()
      .transform((value, originalValue) =>
        String(originalValue).trim() === '' ? null : value
      ),
    minute: yup
      .number()
      .nullable()
      .transform((value, originalValue) =>
        String(originalValue).trim() === '' ? null : value
      ),
    triggerName: yup.string().required(),
  }
);

function TestForm() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    resetField,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  console.log(errors);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (!data.minute && !data.second) {
      alert('on of minute or second field must has value');
      return false;
    }
    alert('success');
    console.log(data);
  };

  const { onChange: onSecondChange, ...secodField } = register('second');
  const { onChange: onMinuteChange, ...minuteField } = register('minute');

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
          inputId="second"
          type="number"
          {...secodField}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onSecondChange(e);
            resetField('minute');
          }}
        />
      <Input
        inputId="minute"
        type="number"
        {...minuteField}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onMinuteChange(e);
          resetField('second');
        }}
      />
      <Input
        inputId="trigger-name"
        label="triggerName"
        {...register('triggerName')}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

I've validated to `minute` or `second` has value in the `onSubmit` function because I don't know exactly your business about filling both or one of them, but if you want you can handle this validation by `yup` by using of `when` method or by defining some custom rule on your schema.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution but it seems it doesn't recognize `resetField`: Property 'resetField' does not exist on type 'UseFormReturn<FieldValues, object>'.ts(2339)

Comment: as an alternative you can do it by using `reset` method, instead of calling `resetField("minute")` or `resetField("second")` you can use `reset({minute: ''})` or `reset({second: ''})`

Comment: @LeoMessi but I believe that if you update your `react-hook-form` version to the latest version your problem will solve with `resetField` type error.

Comment: @LeoMessi did your type issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

import `setValue` from useForm hook and set an onChange function on the input
you can do this for each input and have different behavior for onChange

```
const {
 handleSubmit, 
 setValue, 
 register, 
 reset 
} = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

const onChangeMyInput = (e) => {
 reset()
 setValue('second', e.target.value)
}


<Input 
 {...register('second')} 
 onChange={onChangeMyInput}
 inputId='second' 
 type='number' 
/>
```

Comment: doesn't work this solution